# Google Sheets API v4 write data

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write data to a Google Sheet using the Nodejs API v4. I can sucessfully read and clear data, so I have set everything up correctly. However, using the example in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) for the update method, I cannot work out how to specify the data I want to put in the Google sheet. I would like an example showing how to paste the data held by `const data` into the sheet specified. Here is what I have so far:

```
const data = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
];
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"],
});
const authClient = await auth.getClient();
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: authClient });
const request = {
  spreadsheetId: "my-spreadsheet-id",
  range: "Sheet1!A:E",
  valueInputOption: "",
  resource: {},
  auth: authClient,
};
const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You must specify a value input option

Possible values are:

- `USER_ENTERED`
- `RAW`
- `INPUT_VALUE_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED`

The resource is your data array.

Sample:

```
const request = {
  spreadsheetId: "my-spreadsheet-id",
  range: "Sheet1!A:E",
  valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
  resource: {values: [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
  ]},
  auth: authClient,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to ziganotschka's answer above. It looks like request.resource is now outdated in v4 [as of around Feb 2020](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1966) and it's now necessary to use request.requestBody instead.

Updated Sample:

```js
const request = {
  spreadsheetId: "my-spreadsheet-id",
  range: "Sheet1!A:E",
  valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
  requestBody: {values: [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
  ]},
  auth: authClient,
};
```